# Arch Linux: How to handle patches which only you will use?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, arch-linux, maintenance, patch

I'm using freerdp together with xmonad and it has been giving me a lot of trouble.

The super key (or "windows key") is my mod key in xmonad and it has been interfering with my freerdp usage rather annoyingly. Whenever I switched workspaces (or did anything else in xmonad involving the super key), windows (controlled by the freerdp instance in focus) registered a keypress as well. This event combined with the loss of focus got the super key stuck in windows indefinitely: the press of the keys d and r would first show my desktop, then open the run dialog (as if I was pressing the windows key constantly).

I've tried several versions of freerdp, but all exhibited this annoying behavior. So I resorted to patching freerdp myself to just ignore the left super key on my keyboard. I love free software for a lot of reasons (especially the ability to alter things like this myself), however I still find it annoying to patch and rebuild freerdp on all version (and dependency) changes.

How do you deal with situations like this? Is there even a "right way" to resolve this issue?

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't do this with Windows, so I guess it's sort of a freerdp (&rdesktop) bug....

Answer (score 1):

Try reporting a bug to the original author, and if your patch adds something like a configuration option to choose if disable that or not, they might accept it.

If they don't accept your patch, the only option is to re-patch and re-compile at every release they do.

Comment: Others already did, but it didn't get fixed.

Comment: Did you also send a nice patch they could just merge?